# How to disable a button child component when a cell in a sibling table component is being edited?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to manage the state of two child components - a table and a button via their parent component in a react javascript code (a simplified version of the code):

```
//The Parent component's code
  class Data extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        valid: true
      };
      this.onEdit = this.onEdit.bind(this);
      this.onSave = this.onSave.bind(this);
    }

    onEdit() {
      this.setState({valid: false});
    }

    onSave() {
      this.setState({valid: true});
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          // First child component - the button
          <h4>Data</h4>
          <Control.button
            form={"dataCard"}
            type="submit"
            model="submitdata"
            disabled={{ valid: !this.state.valid }}
            className={"btn btn-primary"}
          >
            Update Data
          </Control.button>

        // Second child component, which wraps a react table inside it
          <DataCard
            onEdit={this.onEdit}
            onSave={this.onSave}
          />
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
}

// Child component's code
render() {
  return (
    <Form
      id="Data"
      model="DataCard"
      onSubmit={values => this.handleSubmit(values)}
    >
      <BootstrapTable
        cellEdit={cellEditFactory({
          mode: "click",
          blurToSave: true,
          onStartEdit: (oldValue, newValue, row, column) => {
             this.props.onEdit();
          },
          afterSaveCell: (oldValue, newValue, row, column) => {
            this.props.onSave();
          }
        })}
      />
    </Form>
  );

}
```

I tried couple of things (for example: maintaining the state in the parent and set it via a callback in the 'DataCard' component), but all of them lead to a rendering loop that made the code crash. I know the best practice is to maintain the state in the parent component and flow it to the child components, but not sure how I can implement it in this particular case.

Comment: The code you have copied is not correct. It's syntactically wrong.

Comment: @MukeshSoni I added the code just to give the feeling about what I'm trying to do. I can fix it if you think it is important for the matter of understanding the question.

Comment: It seems like your parent component is one big component. Makes people make wrong assumptions. Add a link to codesandbox, if possible.

Comment: Can you be more clear on what should be the button's state (disabled/enabled) on `onStartEdit` and on `afterSaveCell` in table.

Comment: @MukeshSoni would love to do that, but I'm not allowed to share the entire code.

Comment: @ravibagul91 I added comments inside the onStartEdit/afterSaveCall that explains the desired state.

Comment: Hi omer, try my solution and let me know if that helps.

Comment: @ravibagul91 I tried something very similar, but it didn't work. I'll give your solution a chance anyway, lets see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Create a `state` to disable / enable the button.

```
state={
   isDisabled:false
}
```

Control your button state using state,

```
<Control.button
   form={"dataCard"}
   type="submit"
   model="submitdata"
   disabled={this.state.isDisabled}  // control's button state 
   className={"btn btn-primary"}
>
   Update Data
</Control.button>
```

Also create two function, to disable or enable the button in parent component only,

```
onEdit = () => {
    this.setState({isDisabled:true})
}

onSave = () => {
    this.setState({isDisabled:false})
}
```

Pass these functions to your child component,

```
<DataCard onEdit={this.onEdit} onSave={this.onSave} />
```

In child component call these functions,

```
<BootstrapTable
  cellEdit={cellEditFactory({
    mode: "click",
    blurToSave: true,
    onStartEdit: (oldValue, newValue, row, column) => {
       // Button state should be set to 'disabled' here
       this.props.onEdit();
    },
    afterSaveCell: (oldValue, newValue, row, column) => {
      // Button state should be set back to 'enabled' here
      this.props.onSave();
    }
  })}
/>
```

Comment: This solution does not solve the problem. I'm still getting the same error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: I can, but it would be exactly what you wrote.

Comment: Yeah, it's ok go ahead.

Comment: Done. Slightly different logic than yours, as I used a flag variable called 'valid' instead of the suggested 'isDisabled', but it shouldn't make a difference

Comment: What is this `disabled={{ valid: !this.state.valid }}`, why not just `disabled={!this.state.valid}`.

Comment: Though it shouldn't matter, I changed it to disabled={!this.state.valid}. I still get the same issue

Comment: The code seems to be ok, but the error generally occurs when we drectly call function inside of render method, which changes state. You should check that, in your parent or child component. Try to console.log in each method and try with log gets printed. check that function invokation and probably that's the issue.

Comment: The onEdit() and onSave() callbacks are called from within the child component's render() method, if that's what you mean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197876/discussion-between-ravibagul91-and-omer).